# I would like the shell print every new line with no space and remove the empty line space as well

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

My shell is printing the output as shown below.

```
$ echo ${mount_check[*]} |tr "." "\n"
File system /abc is NOT mounted
 File system /xyz is NOT mounted

$
```

I had tried using `echo "${mount_check[*]}"` however that didn't  print the output the way I wanted.

I would like the shell print every new line with no space and remove the empty line space as well as shown below.

```
File system /abc is NOT mounted
File system /xyz is NOT mounted
```

As requested by David and tripleee adding the full code.

```
fstable=( $(awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ && !/^ +$/ { print $2 }' /etc/fstab))
mount_check=($(for mount in "${fstable[@]}"; do
if [[ -z $(findmnt -m "$mount") ]]
then
echo "File system $mount is NOT mounted."
fi
done))
```

Comment: What is in `mount_check` and how are you populating the array? Show us `declare -p mount_check`

Comment: How did you populate `mount_check` in the first place? What does it contain, exactly? You have multiple quirks in your `echo` statement and we can't tell if those are beginner errors or something you do on purpose. `echo "${mount_check[@]}"` might do exactly what you want, or at least provide some insights. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: I had in fact tried echo "${mount_check[@]}" .This is how the array is made. ......mount_check=($(for mount in "${fstable[@]}"; do
if [[ -z $(findmnt -m "$mount") ]]
then
echo "File system $mount is NOT mounted."
fi
done))

Comment: Not to be too dense, but where does `fstable` come from? `lsblk`? Your `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your goal is to create an array mount_check[] with the status of all mounts, this loop:

```
mount_check=($(for mount in "${fstable[@]}"; do
if [[ -z $(findmnt -m "$mount") ]]
then
echo "File system $mount is NOT mounted."
fi
done))
```

should be this instead:

```
mount_check=()
for mount in "${fstable[@]}"; do
    mount_status=$(findmnt -m "$mount")
    if [[ -z "$mount_status" ]]
    then
        mount_status="File system $mount is NOT mounted."
    fi
    mount_check+=( "$mount_status" )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your complete requirement, so going by your question specific to fix your problem.

`awk` solution:

```
echo "${mount_check[*]}" | awk -F'mounted.' '{gsub(/ File/,"File");print $1 FS ORS $2 FS}'
```

OR non-one liner for of above solution:

```
echo "${mount_check[*]}" |\ 
awk -F'mounted.' '
{
  gsub(/ File/,"File")
  print $1 FS ORS $2 FS
}'
```

I am considering that your output will always going to have `File` string in output.

***What this solution will take care of is:***

- This will NOT print space which is coming in your 2nd line when you used `tr` command.
- 2nd thing it will take care of is, the empty line, which will NOT be printed.

---

---

If you want to stick with your code `tr` one then try following.

```
echo "${mount_check[*]}" |tr '.' '\n' | sed -E 's/^ +//g;/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never used those variables for anything else, you can simply add those tweaks to the Awk script itself.

```
awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ && !/^ +$/ {
    p = $2 ; sub(/[.]/, "", p); print p}' /etc/fstab
```